# RedShift - update table with date from a timestamp column

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, timestamp, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a table named `adata` in redshift which contains a column `timestamp` with integer type data variable.  The `timestamp` column holds the timestamp as epoch values.  I have added a new column called `rdate` with date variable type.  I am trying to insert date value into `rdate` column by converting the `timestamp` column.

**What is working;**

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second' AS rdate from adata;
```

This prints the rdate column with timestamp as date and time nicely.

**what is not working**

```
insert into adata (rdate) select timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second' AS rdate from adata;
```

I tried with an update statement:

```
update adata set rdate = (select timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second' AS rdate from adata);


ts              rdate
1611306839      need date here
1611469226      need date here
1611399334      need date here
1611373685      need date here
```

another option which I tried:

```
update adata set rdate = (select (timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second') AS rdate from adata);
```

Comment: For the time being I have created another table and inserted data into the new table.

Comment: Try: `UPDATE adata SET rdate = timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second'`

Comment: I've used the exact SQL you are having trouble with so I'd guess the issue is more basic.  What error are you getting?  I think have a column named the same as a reserved word may be in play.  The first timestamp in your sql is a reserved word but the second is a column reference. Try - insert into adata (rdate) select timestamp 'epoch' + "timestamp" * interval '1 second' AS rdate from adata;

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Many thanks...your solution works...I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @BillWeiner  Many thanks for your suggestion...however, I cannot change the column header as it is provided by my client as a larger dump. Thank you again for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to **update existing rows in a table**. In that case, you would use an `UPDATE` command.

Since the rows will be updated based upon the value of other columns in the same table, you could simply use:

```sql
UPDATE adata SET rdate = timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp * interval '1 second'
```

where `timestamp` is the column that contains the existing value.

(Using `INSERT` would add additional rows, which probably isn't what you are seeking.)